# What is the full list of monsters that can be summoned with the Summon Monster spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

On the Pathfinder SRD the lists as shown currently are, according to what I have read on the Paizo messageboards, not entirely accurate nor are all calculations done correctly for the various templates. I've also read in a few places that there are a bunch of types of, for example, elementals that can summoned.

What I would like to find a good link to and reference for is the full list of legal (ideally "legal for Pathfinder Society play") monsters that can be summoned with each fo the Summon Monster spells (I'm not playing a Druid so don't care as much about the Summon Nature's Ally spells). In the best case this resource would show all of the game stats as they would be used in gameplay during a Pathfinder Society game - so average HP, all bonuses calculated correctly etc. I don't have Augmented Summoning but it would be good to see the stats with Augmented Summoning (but also without). Calculating some bonuses and attack options can be tricky. In an even better case this resource would include full descriptions of all special attacks and feats each monster possesses (i.e. be a standalone resource useable even offline).

Answer (score 8):

Are you using the Paizo PRD?  Yeah, it's not curated as well. The [Summon Monster list on d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) is up to date and accurate as far as I know, and is linked by the [Summoner Handbook](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=184592). It doesn't describe every single feat inline, but does the important specials.

Oh, also, there's an iPhone app I use called [Summoner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECo09pVLkbw) that has Pathfinder summoned monster stats in it that applies Augment Summoning, the various templates, etc. You can drill down to get descriptions of most abilities. You might find that helpful. (It's available on Android too.)

Comment: actually I was using the d20PFSRD website but that's the one that is apparently slightly off - I was told that per discussion board comments the dog, Riding in the Level 1 list is an error - it should just be a basic dog (which is a lot less useful). I hadn't seen the iPhone app, I'll look at that! Thanks!

Comment: The official SRD also has the riding dog http://paizo.com/PRD/spells/summonMonster.html, and the only recent Paizo messageboard thread says "use the riding dog" - http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoPublishing/pathfinder/pathfinderRPG/rules/ridingDogSummonMonsterI&page=1

Comment: hmm - good to know. Confusing however as the dog, riding is notably better than most of the other level 1 (and even many of the level 2) monster options

Answer (score 1):

A couple follow-ups on this post (as I'm building my first "Wild Mystic" PF Druid) to help with Druidic summoning:

- Sad, but true: The [d20PFSRD Summon Monster I table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) has now changed "Riding Dog" to "Dog" (with a '?' stating that this was updated in the 5th printing).  Still not a terrible 1st level choice.
- For Druid's, there's an Android App [Player's AAA: Nature's Ally](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fourwinds.com.nature&hl=en) - $0.99 on the play store.  It's reasonable for the price.  All stats have both the plain and Augment Summoning (Str/Con +4 effect) listed.  Only complaint so far is the UI is a bit squished on a N4/phone display.

Comment: This is not an answer. please amplify your answer to answer the question. Comments are not for chatting. If you have questions, please ask them as questions.

Answer (score 1):

For Android I use the following app: [Monster Summoning AAA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fourwinds.com.monstersummon&hl=en_GB)

It lists all monsters by spell, gives you the celestial and fiendish templates added on, plus the augmented stats in brackets for each beastie.

You can also search the list as well. Very handy I've found.

Comment: Aha - looks like another $0.99 Player's AAA app (same publisher as the one I listed), but this one geared toward the Summoner/Monster Summoning spells.